# i am trying to solve two sums in leet code using python can you correct it?

Tags: python

```
list_=[]
a=int(input("enter range"))
for i in range(0,a):
    ele=int(input())
    list_.append(ele)
print(list_)
target=int(input())
list2=[]

if list_[x]+list_[y]==target:
    list2.append(x,y)
    print(list2)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your list to find the pairs of values that match your target

```
list_=[]
a=int(input("enter range"))
for i in range(0,a):
    ele=int(input())
    list_.append(ele)
print(list_)
target=int(input())
list2=[]
for x in list_:
  y = target - x
  if y in list_:
    list2.append((x,y))
print(list2)
```